# Does the Australian Telecommunications and other legislation amendment Act 2018 put resrictions on indaviduals or OSS?

Tags: australia, is-x-legal, encryption

The [Telecommunications and other legislation amendment (assistance and access) act 2018](https://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdb/au/legis/cth/num_act/taolaaaa2018643/) allows the issuing of three types of notice relating to access to encrypted communication, either requesting information (Technical Assistance Requests), requiring delivery of information (Technical Assistance Notices) or requiring the building of interception capability (Technical Capability Notices).  There is very little information available to the public about how it is used, and this seems to be by design as there are [hefty penalties for revealing any aspect of a notice](https://www.zdnet.com/article/whats-actually-in-australias-encryption-laws-everything-you-need-to-know/). [Al Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2018/12/6/australia-encrypted-data-bill-passes-first-hurdle) reports that "individuals could face a prison sentence" but give no information about what this may be for.

If an individual in Australia used [OpenPGP](https://www.openpgp.org/) to encrypt their communication would either the individual or the developers be subject notices issued under this law?

Comment: The Minister for Home Affairs publishes [annual reports](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/about-us/our-portfolios/national-security/lawful-access-telecommunications/telecommunications-interception-and-surveillance) on the use of powers under the *Telecommunications (Interception and Access) Act 1979*. The "industry assistance" powers are addressed in [chapter 5 of the latest report](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/nat-security/files/telecommunications-interception-access-act-1979-annual-report-20-21.pdf#page=75).

Answer (score 0):

### It doesn’t apply to end users

Section [317C](https://www.austlii.edu.au/cgi-bin/viewdoc/au/legis/cth/num_act/taolaaaa2018643/sch1.html) is broad but it doesn’t capture end users.

So, a notice could be served on the developers of OpenPGP (or any intermediary such as a website hosting the software) and the would be subject to sanction if they did not comply.

It could not be served on a private user. However, there are other laws in Australia that can require an individual to disclose passwords to encrypted communications subject to common law protections on self-incrimination which are generally not applicable in national security matters.